# Reading XML file results in index out of range exception

Tags: c#, xml

Using C# I have an XML file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Account>
    <name>Jani</name>
  </Account>
</root>
```

and I also have a function to read the name node as:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("lib//user.xml");
XmlNode node;
node = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
string name = node.Attributes[0].Value;
label1.Text = name.ToString();
```

but I am getting index out of range error as:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: You need the `Elements` and not the `Attributes`. Happened to me :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
node = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
string name = node.Attributes[0].Value;
```

`node` is your *root* node. Which looks like this:

```
<root>
```

How many attributes does it have? None, as it turns out. An *attribute* in XML is one of these `bar="baz"` things:

```
<foo bar="baz">
```

`node.Attributes[0]` refers to the *first* attribute. There is no first attribute, there's no second attribute -- you didn't use attributes in this XML at all. Hence, that's out of range. There's no first item in an empty collection.

What you want is an element named `name`, which is farther down inside your XML tree.

Probably this:

```
var node = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/root/Account/name");
```

And then you'll want to look at `node.InnerText` to get `"Jani"` out of it.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I am not getting any error now but the result is empty. Nothing display on lable!

Comment: @MonaCoder I just fixed an error in my answer: `node.Value` was wrong. I should have made it `node.InnerText` instead. Did you try `InnerText`?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read `node.Attributes[0].Value` but there is no attribtues in your sample XML file. Not sure of the exact syntax but it should probably be closer to `node.Value`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other answers, your current XML does not have attributes.

```
    private void DoIt()
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(@"M:\StackOverflowQuestionsAndAnswers\38924171\38924171\data.xml");
        XmlNode node;
        node = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        //string name = node.Attributes[0].Value;
        string name = node["Account"].InnerText;
    }
```

If your XML did have attributes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Account name="Jani" />
</root>
```

Then you could do this:

```
    private void DoItAgain()
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(@"M:\StackOverflowQuestionsAndAnswers\38924171\38924171\data2.xml");
        XmlNode node;
        node = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        string name = node["Account"].Attributes[0].Value;
    }
```